# Shortest code to link to CSS and JS file

Tags: templating

Is there a helper tag to output a complete stylesheet link.

I used helper tag for lack of knowledge. Helper tag is used in Statamic.

In Statamic `{{ theme:css src="style" tag="true" }}` outputs

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/themes/redwood/css/style.css" />`

I've seen `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ siteUrl }}assets/css/happylager.css">` in Happy Lager's template but I'm looking for something shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Craft there's [`{% includeJsFile %}`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/includejsfile) and [`{% includeCssFile %}`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/includecssfile) which get injected on the `getHeadHtml()` and `getFootHtml()` functions on your templates.